# Sencha-Touch Panel listener

Tags: event-handling, sencha-touch, panel

I have a problem abaout Sencha. I would like to make some calculations when a panel visually deactivated. I think 'deactive' public event had to supply this. but i didn't do that for all the things that i tried. is there anybody have any idea?

```
var hastaDetayCard;
enlil.views.HastaDetay = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    scroll: 'vertical',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    cls: 'hasta-detay',
    listeners:{
        el:
        {
            deactive:function()
            {                   
//              /////calculations;
                }        
        },
        scope:this
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The event is **deactivate**, not **deactive**.
And you probably don't need to put it into the element ("el:{..}" stuff in your code).